# Generate XML reports with Ant, but how to?

Tags: xml, ant, junit

At the moment I want to get the test results in Jenkins. The only problem I'm dealing with is that I can get the XML reports from my Junit Tests. So my question is:

1. Is there a possibility to start the tests with Jenkins and get the results?
2. Or is it possible to generate the xml reports with Ant, and how? Because I had this but don't understand it 100%:

Path to my tests:

- nl\company\cms\plugin\test\AllTests.java (Test Suite)
- CopyOfMyTestClass.java (Single Test Class)
- MyTestClass.java (Single Test Class)

Path to my libraries:

- lib\junit-4.10.jar
- lib\ant.jar (This one is necessary in my plugin, May be also necessary for building XML reports?)

This code I get from the JUnit site: http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_6

---

I understand the following:
`${test.reports}` = Location where you want your test reports
`${classes}` = The bin directory where the .java files are already build into .class files. Is it also possible to forward them to the .java files?

But I don't know what to do with the following:

```
<classpath refid="test.classpath" />
```

Thanks already!

**Update**

He found my 3 testclasses and he build a report, but I get the same error in this three classes in the report:

test.AllTests

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.AllTests
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
```

This is my build.xml code:

```
<property name="basedir" value="C:/CMSdot2"/>
<property name="classes" value="C:/CMSdot2/dotCMS/WEB-INF/classes/nl/company/dotcms/plugin"/>
<property name="test.reports" value="${basedir}/dotCMS/"/>
<target name="test-html">
 <junit fork="yes" printsummary="no" haltonfailure="no">
  <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.reports}" >
   <fileset dir="${classes}">
    <include name="**/*Test*.class" />
   </fileset>
  </batchtest>
  <formatter type="xml" />
  <classpath id="test.classpath">
   <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.10.jar"/>
  </classpath>
 </junit>
 <junitreport todir="${test.reports}">
  <fileset dir="${test.reports}">
   <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
  </fileset>
  <report todir="${test.reports}" />
 </junitreport>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to specify `${classes}` to point to the classes. Java needs classes to execute programs/junit so `.java` file won't do.
2. You need `<classpath refid="test.classpath" />` to include your classes and any eyternal lib if you have external libs (like log4j, or apache commons) that are needed to run your tests. For example:

   ```
   <classpath id="test.classpath">
       <pathelement location="${classes}" />
       <pathelement location="lib/ther.jar"/>
   </classpath>
   ```

Comment: I'm getting close to it. He found the Test classes and he makes a report. But in the report he said: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException I have updated the first post

Comment: is your package testen.AllTests OR test.AllTests? There seems to be some confusion with the classes dir I suppose.

Comment: It is the package Test, not testen So it is correct that he go to test.AllTests. I changed it in the first post!

Comment: sorry my mistake :D the classpath for test.classpath has to include the root folder of your java classes, i edited the answer. What I find more curious is that you say your package is called test and not nl.company.dotcms.plugin.test. Your package structure seems a bit odd.

Comment: Sorry your right it is: nl.company.dotcms.plugin.test But it still don't works for me.. I get this error now, a bit different: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/AllTests (wrong name: nl/company/dotcms/plugin/test/AllTests)

Comment: thats because you need to point classes to: C:/CMSdot2/dotCMS/WEB-INF/classes/. This is where the package structure starts :).

Comment: But that is what I'm doing with this? : <property name="classes" value="C:/CMSdot2/dotCMS/WEB-INF/classes/nl/company/dotcms/plugin"/>

Comment: this is wrong! the classpath has to start at the root of the package. Before the nl/company/... You have to use C:/CMSdot2/dotCMS/WEB-INF/classes/. This is the package and folder convention in java.